# this.domNode is null

Tags: javascript, jquery, dojo, widget

I am trying to use jquery to load a dojo chart. I am using this code. However in the second click, in the first button i get this error. The same occurs if i click in the first button, click in the second and click again in the first. This problem is Driving me crazy.

[demo here](http://74.52.141.77/~dnsmont/test1/)

[image]

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.lista_').click(function () {
        $.get('index1.php', function (data) {
            dojo.addOnLoad(function () {
                require(["dojo/_base/xhr", "dojo/parser", "dojo/dom"], function (xhr, parser, dom) {
                    var um = [];
                    dijit.registry.filter(function (w) { //problem here, maybe this code destroy something that should not be destroyed
                        if (dojo.indexOf(um)) {
                            w.destroyRecursive();
                        }
                    });
                    $('#paginas').html(data);

                    dojo.parser.parse(dojo.byId('paginas'));

                });
            });
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Try to use a js file used in debugging and not a minimized one. this is for easier debugging.,

Comment: Just wonder why are you using two javascript frameworks ?

Comment: well, it's irrelevant to the question. I am only using dojo to create the charts.

Comment: @Farmor the file is included by require. If i try to make a normal load like <script src> the file will show me lots of errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to remove the old chart before inserting/parsing the new one, but I don't think that is happening. This may cause Dojo to barf up various errors.

```
dijit.registry.filter(function (w) { //problem here, maybe this code destroy something that should not be destroyed
    if (dojo.indexOf(um)) {
        w.destroyRecursive();
    }
});
```

I'm not sure what you are doing here. The `filter` function will return an array of widget's for which the callback returns true. Additionally, `dojo.indexOf` is used to search for an element in an array (I'm not sure what sort of black magic you are doing with it there :P).

I think (if I've understood your intentions), you should rather do:

```
dijit.registry.findWidgets(dojo.byId("paginas")).forEach(function(w) {
    w.destroy();
});
```

This will destroy the widget(s) inside #paginas before inserting and parsing the newly fetched HTML.

**Edit:** When you click the 2nd button, and the chart is removed, the `<style>` tag is removed too. That's why you see artifacts from the tooltip div, because it's no longer hidden by CSS. You can solve this by having the claro.css import in the main file, i.e. put this:

```
<style type="text/css">
@import "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.7/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css";   
</style>
```

in the main file's header instead of in the HTML you load with jquery (index1.php).

Comment: thanks for your answer. The link is now updated with your suggestion. But there is a problem when we click in the second button, after the first. You need to activate the tooltip to reproduce the problem. Some divs are not removed.

Comment: @Daniel Hmm, I'm not seeing the errors on the updated page. You are right that the tooltip divs aren't removed, but I'm not sure they are a problem because they don't have an explicit id (and tooltip is sort of a singleton).

Comment: There is no errors now. The only issue is the stuff of the tooltip that is not removed. And if i destroy by body or something i will get the initial error this.domNode is null

Comment: @Daniel Ah, I see now. I updated the answer with a suggestion.

Comment: man, you save my day. After tomorrow i will start a bounty  for you.

Comment: @Daniel You are too kind! Happy coding, and have a great weekend.